# How do I move a custom view through the whole layout of android app?

Tags: android, view, kotlin

I'm trying to move a custom view (a small circle) over the whole application layout by using proportional x and y values. Let's say for example, that I want to move the circle to exactly the middle of the screen, so I'll send (0.5f, 0.5f) and then multiply each value by my current screen width and height respectively. But for some reason the circle ends up somewhere else, like (0.5, 0.5) ending up at the bottom right of the screen, just as if I where using wrong and larger resolution values, which I'm not, since I've even hardcoded my device resolution to make sure that's not the problem.

Here is my custom view current implementation:

```
class CirclePointer(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) :View(context, attrs){

 override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
     super.onDraw(canvas)

     canvas.apply {
         this!!.drawCircle(x, y, 5f, mCirclePointerPaint)
     }
 }

 private val mCirclePointerPaint = Paint().apply {
 }

 fun move(newX: Float, newY: Float){
     x = newX * 1280// hardcoded width
     y = newY * 720// hardcoded height

     invalidate()
     requestLayout()
 }// end of move

 override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
     super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
 }

}
```

And my activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/heading"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <my.package.annotation_views.CirclePointer
    android:id="@+id/circlePointer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've just leant how to implement my own custom View so I'm pretty sure I'm missing something. So any help would be appreciated.

**What I've tried**

- Setting my CirclePointer width and height to match_parent instead of wrap_content

**Observations**

I'm using Android Studio 3.2 and macOS Mojave

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, it's not exactly a solution but for some unknown reason if I use half the actual width and height the pointer movement is reproduced at the exact position it should...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

making the x and y of the circle in the half of your screen width and height respectively will not work because your circle's x and y are the top left of your circle not the center of the circle. The solution is to subtract half of the width from the x, and half of height from y such as:

```
int left = screenWidth / 2 - circleWidth / 2
int top = screenHeight / 2 - circleHeight / 2
yourCircle.setX(left);
yourCircle.setY(top);
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand that and will definitely update my code to subtract half the circle radius. But my offset is far greater than that, I mean, my circle has a radius of 5px and when positioned half of the screen it ends up even outside the drawing area. I think I'll start playing with the hardcoded width and height to see if I can find any correlations on the offset...

Comment: I will accept this as a correct answer since it's the right way to position the circle at the exact desired coordinates. Thanks for your time @Khalid Taha